# Laravel: how to pass query parameters with the same name as route parameters

Tags: php, laravel

I have a route

```
Route::get('/edit/{id}', 'EditController')->name('edit');
```

I have a route param named id, but I also need query param id, example:

```
/edit/1?id=9999
```

When I use

```
route('edit', ['id' => 1])
```

Only route param is passed

```
/edit/1
```

Since query param name can not change, I would like to ask if there is any other way other than

- Change the route param

```
Route::get('/edit/{someOtherName}', 'EditController')->name('edit');
```

- Concat query string

```
route('edit', ['id' => 1]) . "?" . http_build_query(['id' => 9999])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you would need to either change the route key name or manually append the query string to the generated url.

The `route` helper's signature is

```
// Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php
function route($name, $parameters = [], $absolute = true)
```

It does not have a way to specify query parameters and route parameters separately. The `$parameters` array accounts for both.

Eventually, the `route()` helper will call the `Illuminate\Routing\RouteUrlGenerator` class's `to` method which has a very similar signature

```php
// Illuminate/Routing/RouteUrlGenerator.php
public function to($route, $parameters = [], $absolute = false)
{
    $domain = $this->getRouteDomain($route, $parameters);

    // First we will construct the entire URI including the root and query string. Once it
    // has been constructed, we'll make sure we don't have any missing parameters or we
    // will need to throw the exception to let the developers know one was not given.
    $uri = $this->addQueryString($this->url->format(
        $root = $this->replaceRootParameters($route, $domain, $parameters),
        $this->replaceRouteParameters($route->uri(), $parameters),
        $route
    ), $parameters);

    if (preg_match_all('/{(.*?)}/', $uri, $matchedMissingParameters)) {
        throw UrlGenerationException::forMissingParameters($route, $matchedMissingParameters[1]);
    }

    // Once we have ensured that there are no missing parameters in the URI we will encode
    // the URI and prepare it for returning to the developer. If the URI is supposed to
    // be absolute, we will return it as-is. Otherwise we will remove the URL's root.
    $uri = strtr(rawurlencode($uri), $this->dontEncode);

    if (! $absolute) {
        $uri = preg_replace('#^(//|[^/?])+#', '', $uri);

        if ($base = $this->request->getBaseUrl()) {
            $uri = preg_replace('#^'.$base.'#i', '', $uri);
        }

        return '/'.ltrim($uri, '/');
    }

    return $uri;
}
```

There, the route keys are replaced from the `$parameters` array and what is left over gets added to the query string.

Since PHP does not support having duplicate keys in it's associative arrays, you are stuck with the two solutions you came up with.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this

```
url('/edit/'.1.'?id='.9999)
```

And in controller you can get id parameter by using this

```
request()->query('id')
```

It will return 9999, and for getting 1 you can simply pass it as like this

```
public function edit($id){
   // it will return 1
   dd($id);
  // it will return 9999 
  request()->query('id')
  
}
```

Comment: I think using route is better.
Because if using url when path is changed, url will have to modified manually but route won't